# Unable to select the correct div from a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to parse song titles from a website, but can't figure out how to grab the specific div that has them.  I've tried about a dozen different methods but always get back an empty list.

If you go to the url and inspect one of the youtube videos there, you will find a div with a class of `single-post-oembed-youtube-wrapper`. That element also contains the artist and title of the song.

This is my first time attempting to scrape data from a webpage, can someone help me out?

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pprint
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import sys

html = None
url = 'https://ultimateclassicrock.com/best-rock-songs-2018/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"single-post-oembed-youtube-wrapper'"})

#all_songs = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'single-post-oembed-youtube-wrapper')
#html = all_songs.get_attribute("outerHTML")

pprint.pprint(divs)
browser.close()
```

Comment: What, no upvotes??

Comment: From me +1 . You are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try to retrieve the data directly from the HTML source, thus avoiding Selenium.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

url = "https://ultimateclassicrock.com/best-rock-songs-2018/"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content)

results = []
for elem in soup.find_all("strong"):
    if "," in elem.text:
        results.append(elem.text.split(", "))

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["artist", "song"])
df
```

Output:

```
    artist  song
0   Steve Perry     'Sun Shines Gray'
1   Paul McCartney  'I Don't Know'
2   Judas Priest    'Flamethrower'
3   Ace Frehley     'Rocking With the Boys'
4   Paul Simon  'Questions for the Angels'
...
```

This is slightly hacky but works with your example.

Comment: This worked best for my needs, Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad that you could solve your problem. All the best!

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all(".single-post-oembed-youtube-wrapper+div p strong")
```

This will give you all the titles there

Comment: omg that's awesome!
In all of my googling to make this work I never saw this format anywhere, where would I have learned this from?

Comment: To say the truth - I never practiced BS4. All I know - Selenium and locators :) Here I just found the locator matching titles and by googling saw how to use CSS Selectors with soup :)

Answer (score 2):

You can grab all the required data from  `API`

```
import requests

api_url= 'https://ultimateclassicrock.com/rest/carbon/api/menu/category/album-reviews/'
headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
data=[]

res=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)
#print(res)

for item in res.json()['widgets']['dataDetails'].values():
    title = item['data']['mainData']['title']
```

**Output:**

```
Reissue Roundup: Summer Sets From Blondie, Lou Reed and More
Todd Rundgren, &apos;Space Force&apos;: Album Review
Pink Floyd, &apos;Animals (2018 Remix)&apos;: Album Review
Sammy Hagar and the Circle, &apos;Crazy Times&apos;: Album Review
Ringo Starr, &apos;EP3&apos;: Album Review
Billy Idol, &apos;The Cage EP&apos;: Album Review
Beatles, &apos;Revolver Special Edition (Super Deluxe)&apos;: Album Review
Richard Marx, &apos;Songwriter&apos;: Album Review
The Cult, &apos;Under the Midnight Sun&apos;: Album Review
Various, &apos;Here It Is: A Tribute to Leonard Cohen&apos;: Album Review
Red Hot Chili Peppers, &apos;Return of the Dream Canteen&apos;: Review
Skid Row, &apos;The Gang&apos;s All Here&apos;: Album Review
```